# Cannot catch or trap syntax error

Tags: powershell, windows-7, powershell-3.0

I am aware about the nasty behaviour of powershell dealing with syntax errors and exit codes. I have the following repro case which should be caught by either the trap or the try catch block, but none of them is triggered, even with `$ErrorActionPreference` set to `stop`.

This code here keeps exiting with error code 0, which is quite annoying as no trap mechanism is called dealing with the error:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"
trap [Exception] {
    echo "Trap encountered"
    exit(1)
}

Try
{

   function foo($path, $path)
   {
   }

}

Catch
{
    echo "Caught something"
    exit(1)
}
```

Does somebody know how I can trick powershell to properly exit in such cases? Syntax errors in scripts break our CI silently which is quite a problem.

For clarity: This has been tested and reproduced on Win 7 PS 3.0

Edit 2: To avoid more people saying that I won't catch syntax errors by this. Powershell is designed different that most other script or programming languages you know.

You can catch syntax errors as they are treated as terminating errors.

> If you make a syntax error or run out of memory, that is a terminating error. Terminating errors can be caught and handled.

See http://www.vexasoft.com/blogs/powershell/7255220-powershell-tutorial-try-catch-finally-and-error-handling-in-powershell

Comment: for me it errors out: "function foo($path, $path)
+                        ~~~~~
Duplicate parameter $path in parameter list."

Comment: On my system, `powershell -command "function foo($a, $a) {}"` has an exit code of 1, while a successful run exits with 0. Detecting the error from your CI should at least be feasible. If you really want to handle this from PowerShell itself, you could of course recursively invoke (blech) or you could try leveraging the [`Parser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.management.automation.language.parser) class (from 3.0 onwards) to parse any scripts before executing them.

Comment: @4c74356b41 It does, but no trap is called and if you check the exit code, it will be 0, regardless of the red error text.

Comment: @JeroenMostert This is an example our scripts are far more complex and our CI performs powershell -f tempfile.ps1. The usage of powershell -command seems to be discouraged. Parsers won't work here as this script is put into a temporary file by CI, I have no access to it.

Comment: @Samuel: it was intended as an example. `powershell -f .\script.ps1` does exactly the same thing with regards to exit codes. Try it yourself from `cmd` (`powershell somethingsomething || echo %errorlevel%`). I also don't get why parser wouldn't work. The script is put there by CI, but surely *you* determine the contents of the script? Otherwise your question is more about how to make your CI not output invalid scripts...

Comment: @JeroenMostert I cannot confirm this, on a Win 7 machine calling `powershell -f badscript.ps1` followed by `echo "error %ERRORLEVEL%"` does not echo anything and if I call `echo "error %ERRORLEVEL%"` afterwards in the same shell, it returns "error 0"

Comment: @Samuel: this may depend on the PowerShell version then (or the Windows version, but that's very unlikely). I'm running PowerShell 5 on Windows 10. PowerShell 5 is available for W7 (and server versions) as part of WMF 5.0, if that helps.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I added PS 3.0 and Win 7 tag. I will test this on a Win10 machine ASAP. I remember there was some behaviour change either between some PS versions or Windows release (but I suspect PS versions)

Comment: This way you won't catch errors. Since its not actually an exception it won't be even executed since parses says theres syntax error.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Can Confirm that the code above produces expected behaviour on Win 10 with PS 5.1. Now I need to make that work on 3.0

Answer (score 1):

Try/Catch catch execution errors, not parser errors.  Parser errors will happen before powershell even starts executing the script. Rather than calling your script directly, can you call it through a helper script, one which is known to always have good syntax. e.g. `ScriptInvoker.ps1`

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
    [string]$Path
)
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"

try { &$Path }
catch { exit(1) }
```

Now your CI system just needs to output your temp script to `temp.ps1`, but rather than calling `powershell -File temp.ps1`, use `powershell -File ScriptInvoker.ps1 temp.ps1`.

Comment: Your assumption about powershell seems wrong: > If you make a syntax error or run out of memory, that is a terminating error. Terminating errors can be caught and handled.
http://www.vexasoft.com/blogs/powershell/7255220-powershell-tutorial-try-catch-finally-and-error-handling-in-powershell

Comment: Why do you say a syntax error is a terminating error.  A terminating error happens during the *execution* of powershell.  A syntax failure happens before any code even starts to execute.

Comment: I dont say that, this is a quote from the mentioned link in my comment. Further more it works on Win 10

Answer (score 0):

I think that PS Script Analyzer does what you would want it to do. https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer

So for me it works like this:

try {Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer -ErrorAction Stop -Path .\ } catch {Write-Output $_}
Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer : Parse error in file C:\Users\gleb_boushev\Desktop\Untitled2.ps1:  Duplicate parameter $path in parameter list at line 10 column 24.